# Refresh code without overwriting my changes

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I am fairly new to git..

I was working on something and found that a previous commit had an error that I wanted to fix right away. So I edited it using bitbucket's web editor, then committed the changes.

Now I am not sure how to get the changes without overwriting my local current edits (I am not ready to commit my current changes yet)

I am using BitBucket's source-tree software. So my question is, what function can I use to grab the repo without overwriting my local uncommitted edits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you familiar with [stashing](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)?  I would recommend the following:

1. Stash all of your local changes that you want to keep.  This can be done from source tree by clicking the stash button at the top of your screen.  You should see your stash in the list of stashes on the left side of the screen.
2. After verifying your work is stashed, pull in any changes you want to pull.
3. Finally, click on your earlier stash to apply the changes to your newly updated code.

Comment: This is the answer.. I will accept it when SO lets me.. Thanks for the quick and descriptive answer.. Learned a whole new feature today!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
git stash
git fetch && git rebase // do what ever you want
git stash apply
```

Comment: I like / prefer `git stash apply` (vs `git stash pop`) but be sure to use `git stash drop` when you're all done with the stash.  The `pop` command is just "apply, then drop immediately if successfully applied" so some people prefer that.

Answer (score 0):

```
git stash
git pull
git stash pop
```